# How to resize PDF in Acrobat (CS3)?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

Easy question - I have PDF, which is high resolution, but set to small page.

I just want to take the PDF and resize it.

I have Adobe Acrobat 8 Professional (mac os x version).

Comment: Do you have the original source document?

Comment: No, I don't, sadly. All I have is the PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I answered it myself...

As I said, I use OS X. In OS X, you can print anything from almost any application to PDF.

However, it doesn't work in Acrobat (it tells you to use Save instead of PDF printing). Therefore, I had to open it in Preview and print it to PDF - with different page size - from preview.

...and that's pretty much it.